# split a collection into pairs of two

Tags: j

I need to find pairs of matching elements in a list after the list has been grouped by twos.

I.e. `1 1 2 3 2 2` would return `1 1 2 2`, but `1 2 2 1` would return nothing because the twos would be in different boxes.

My idea was to create boxes, then apply a mask to get the matching pairs, but I can't figure out the pairwise boxing step. How would I do pairwise boxing?

(Another solution to my problem would be interesting as well, but I'm interested in the pairwise boxing solution)

Answer (score 2):

Generally it is better to use boxes in situations where you are dealing with variable-sized lists. Where that isn't the case, it is best to avoid them to improve performance (increase speed and reduce space). This version doesn't use boxes:

```
   _2 ,@(]\ #~ =/\) 1 1 3 4 2 2
1 1 2 2
   _2 ,@(]\ #~ =/\) 1 2 2 1
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work.

```
   _2 ]\ 1 2 2 1
1 2
2 1
```

It is based on the dyad u\ called Infix. More about that at this link: http://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/d430.htm

To box, just apply the adverb `\` to the box verb `<`

```
   _2 <\ 1 2 4 5 4 6 2 1
+---+---+---+---+
|1 2|4 5|4 6|2 1|
+---+---+---+---+
```

Comment: Or just use `_2 <\ 1 2 4 5 4 6 2 1`

Comment: Should have seen that really, shouldn't I. Thanks for cleaning up Tikkanz.

Comment: And actually since Dane has since cleaned up my answer, originally it was `_2<@]\ 1 2 4 5 4 6 2 1` which is what Tikkanz was pointing out.

Answer (score 1):

Building on Bob's answer, you can apply the conditional verb on pairs of values as well with the [Infix (`\`) adverb](http://code.jsoftware.com/wiki/Vocabulary/bslash#dyadic):

```
   _2 =/\ 1 1 2 3 2 2
1 0 1
```

A straightforward way to apply this conditional and end up with the boxed results follows, assuming that you need the results boxed (which you don't in this simple example):

```
   ((_2 =/\ ]) # _2 <\ ]) 1 2 2 1

   ((_2 =/\ ]) # _2 <\ ]) 1 1 2 3 2 2
┌───┬───┐
│1 1│2 2│
└───┴───┘
```

In case it's unclear, the above calculates the conditional with the parenthesized `(_2 =/\ ])`. The fork rule applies `_2 <\ ]` to box the pairs, then selects the boxes that match the conditional result with the `f # g` fork.